# Retrieving _servletName from HttpServletRequest object

Tags: java, http, servlets

I was wondering if there was a way to retrieve the _servletName value from a HttpServletRequest object. I basically need it to identify from which servlet the request came from. The class as such does not provide any methods to retrieve that information

Comment: how about setting an attribute  ?

Comment: How is this question related to spring? -- Should ben the Spring tag removed?

Answer (score 0):

HttpServletRequest.getServletPath()

Did you look at: http://download.oracle.com/javaee/1.3/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html ?

Comment: Hi Thom yes. I tried that and received the "" empty string. Was wondering how to handle that scenario. 
@Ralph : Yes sorry, wrong tag. Thanks Jigar!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try Servlet Config way?

```
ServletConfig sg=getServletConfig();
System.out.println(sg.getServletName());
```